# Which of these statements about $Q=\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1000}$ is correct?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Pick the correct option regarding $Q$.

> $$Q=\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1000}$$
>   Pick one option:
>
> 1. $Q>1\qquad$ 2. $Q\leq \frac{1}{3}\qquad$ 3. $\frac{1}{3}<Q\leq \frac{2}{3}\qquad$ 4. $\frac{2}{3}<Q\leq 1$

My approach :

$$Q = \frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1000} > \frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{1000}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1000} = \frac{901}{1000}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1000} > \frac{9}{10}$$

So, $Q > 1$. Option 1 is correct.

Now, my question is: can this be proved with some other approach?

Comment: Now, My question is can this be proved with some other approach?

Comment: Simply knowing that $Q>9/10$ is insufficient to conclude that $Q>1$. You've not ruled out option $4$, yet.

Comment: Right, so everything except 4 and 1 have been ruled out.

Comment: Sorry everyone. Can you guide me further?

Comment: $$\sum_{k=p}^{q} \dfrac1k \approx \ln \left(\dfrac{q}p \right) + O(1/p)$$ which gives us that it should be roughly close to $\log(10) > 2 > 1$. So the hunch is option $1$.

Comment: @Marvis sir, I haven't studied about big O notation yet. Can you explain in some other way?

Comment: To complete the proof, you could break the series at 200: $1/100 + \dots + 1/200 > 101/200 > 1/ 2$, and then $1/201+\dots + 1/000 > 800/1000 = 4/5$, and those add up to more than 1. I'm not aware of a fundamentally different approach that is accessible at a precalculus level.

Comment: If you can prove this inequality, $H_n\geq \log(n)\geq H_{n+1}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Divide the sum into two parts:

$$\frac1{100}+\ldots+\frac{1}{500}+\frac1{501}+\ldots+\frac1{1000}$$

The first part, $100$ to $500$ is such that:
$$\frac1{100}+\ldots+\frac{1}{500}>\frac1{500}+\ldots+\frac{1}{500}=\frac{401}{500}$$

The second part, $501$ to $1000$ is such that:
$$\frac1{501}+\ldots+\frac{1}{1000}>\frac1{1000}+\ldots+\frac{1}{1000}=\frac{500}{1000}$$

Therefore the sum of $100$ to $1000$ is larger than $\frac{401}{500}+\frac{500}{1000}$, which itself is larger than $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's proceed with the same sort of approach you tried, but a bit finer.

There are $100$ terms greater than $1/200$, another $100$ terms greater than $1/300$, and so on, up to $100$ terms greater than $1/1000$. But this gives that the sum is greater than $1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + 1/6 + 1/7 + 1/8 + 1/9 + 1/10$, which is about $1.9$, but more importantly is very easily calculatable to be greater than $1$.

Comment: Sir, I got your last line but please elaborate "But this gives that the sum is greater than 1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7+1/8+1/9+1/10,"

Comment: For example, $1/100 + 1/101 + \dots + 1/199 > 100/200 = 1/2$, and repeating we get that the whole sum is greater than $1/2 + 1/3 + \dots + 1/10$

Comment: Thank you sir, now the concept is crystal clear to me.